# Display Serial Port Information Into Textbox

Tags: c#, serial-port

In C#, I have the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
   serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
   serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
   serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
   serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
   serialPort1.Open();
   serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
}
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
   string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

I have an Arduino sending serial data to the comm port continually, and I would like to put the data received into a textbox (with the new entries coming in on a seperate line).

I'm trying to understand the whole += concept, but I'm not sure how to use the code I have to enter the serial data into a textbox... can someone please help me understand this.

Comment: Is your code working? Are you asking about *event* handling or what?

Comment: @ Hans Passant - I disagree. I am slowly trying to learn about Arduino, C#, and robotics. This is just the latest section I am trying to understand. I have the Arduino linked to a force sensor which is outputing serial data, and I would like my C# program to read the data coming into the COM port...

Comment: Why not use textBox1.AppendText("Your text")?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a text box use a RichTextBox so that you can get new lines. I would also suggest making it read only. Also Don't forget to add a line break ("\n") at the end of each incoming string.

the code would look like this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort1.Open();
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
}
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    RichTextBox1.Text += sp.ReadExisting() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I can't put the "richtextbox1" into the section you've described above with the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Arduino_Interface.Form1.richtextbox1'"
Why is this?

Comment: You can get new lines by appending an Environment.NewLine before your message.  No need for a rich text box.

Comment: Add a rich text box to your form. Replace richtextbox1 with the name of your rich text box. If you are using visual studio you should be able to just drag one out of the toolbox onto your form.

Comment: @TheWoo That is because your method is marked `static` remove that and you will be able to modify the RTB from within.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really following what you're asking. Does indata get the data? If so, to add the text to the textbox just:

```
textBox.Text += indata;
```

Comment: Point of note with this; indata in the OP's code is declared inside the DataReceived event, which runs on a different thread to the main UI thread that the textBox control will have been created on. Invoke will likely be required because windows controls should not be accessed by threads other than their creator

Answer (score 0):

In your case listed above the `+=` operator is used to subscribe to an event.

```
serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

Means that when the DataReceived event is raised, it will call `DataReceivedHandler`. For more information, view [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx). In `DataReceivedHandler` simply add`TextBox.Text += indata + "\r\n";` In order to do that, you will need to remove the `static` modifier in your method signature.

In other cases, like with `int` it is the assignment increment operator, for example these are the same

```
int i = 1;
int j = 5;    
j += i;    
//j == 6
```

For `System.String` it is used to concatenate strings together.

```
string name = "John";
name += "Smith";
//name = "JohnSmith"
```